# How do you set the database schema, at the package level, in SPARX Enterprise Architect?

Tags: schema, enterprise-architect

Example:

I have a Data Model with a package called Academic. Inside of Academic, I have tables called Instructor and Student. When I "Generate DDL", I'd like Instructor and Student to be generated as:

```
CREATE TABLE [Academic].[Instructor] ...
CREATE TABLE [Academic].[Student] ...
```

I have tried setting the tagged value named OWNER (EAUML::table::OWNER) on each table (which works), however I'd like to think that I could somehow set this at the package level and have all of the tables within 'inherit' this value. To that end, I tried adding a new tagged value to the package, both as EAUML::table::OWNER and OWNER but it doesn't work as desired.

Ideally I'd like to use the package name as the schema name but it would be acceptable for the schema name to be an individual value, as long as it's only set in one place.

Answer (score 3):

Settings on the package aren't used when generating the schema, so that won't help.

But if you right-click the package in the package browser and select Code Engineering -- Reset DBMS Options, you can change the DBMS type and table owner for all tables in the package.