# Enterprise Architect Compare database

Tags: database, enterprise-architect, datamodel

I am very new to EA and in general data engineering. I want to be able syncronize my MS SQL DB with the data model I created in EA. Using the help and tutorials, I learnt how to push my data model onto the MS SQL DB. What I fail to achieve is the syncronization. I have a feeling that is has to do with the schema. The database builder lists all the orginal tables and then again all tables from the ODBC connection with an additional 'dbo.'

Do i need to define this somwhere in the options of my data model or can I compare the data model with the server taking account of the schema?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there are that many EA-DB specialists here. Geert might have an idea? Anyhow, you should cross post on Sparx' forum (with link to this question since pictures on their board are a PITA).

Comment: thx, you mean this one? https://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php I registered there yesterday and am waiting for an approval.

Comment: Yes. That's the place. There are only a few answering here on SO :-/

Comment: I'm not really sure. I use that feature regularly, and I've never had this particular problem.

Comment: I have the feeling that I just need to take account of the dbo schema. If I import the data model from the server in a new project I am getting al the tables without the dbo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the owner tag dbo to all my tables. For some reson it was not enough to add it to the data model object. Thanks to this thread i found an option to change it for all tables at once.
[How do you set the database schema, at the package level, in SPARX Enterprise Architect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481324/how-do-you-set-the-database-schema-at-the-package-level-in-sparx-enterprise-ar)

There were still some differences about the PK and FK ids when i tried to compare but I just aligned my local data model with that and now there are no differences between the data model and the data base.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work in the “Database Builder” feature of Sparx EA.
This can be found on the "Develop" tab.  (This will not work directly from the “Browser”)
Select the package having the “Database” as its stereotype.  Use mouse button 2 and select “Manage DBMS Options”.  The dialog will enable you to change the table(s) owner or even change the selected DBMS type.  From the database builder you can then perform the "database compare" or "compare with options".
Note regarding terminology - the "dbo" in SQL Server is a the database owner.
(I have also posted this answer to the Sparx Forum.)
You can find the related documentation with screen images here: https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_domains/import_schema_into_builder.html